# check if an array contains values of another array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two list, I want the values of list 1 if it contains any of value from list 2.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("Sunday is far away");
list1.Add("Today is Monday");
list1.Add("Tuesday is too near");

List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Add("Sunday");
list2.Add("Monday");
list2.Add("Tuesday");

var result1 = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y => y.Contains(x))).ToList(); //no results
var result2 = list2.Where(x => list1.Any(y => y.Contains(x))).ToList(); //give values of list2. But I need values of list1
```

**Update:**

I need values of list1 in result, how can I get that?

Comment: so what is the problem here?

Comment: In first approach you messed up x and y. Should be `Any(y => x.Contains(y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple thing you missed, Take a look into the collection, All Items in the first list are larger than that of second, so the contains will return false. So you have to check for second item in first like the following:

Here is your [modified code with result](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LqU1HI):

```
var result1 = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToList(); 
var result2 = list2.Where(x => list1.Any(y => y.Contains(x))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can. If List1 contains any value of List2 then result=List1. Otherwise null;

```
var result = list2.Any(l2 => list1.Contains(l2))==true?list1:null;
```